# git_checkout_tree() with conflicts, can it write the conflicting blocks into files?

Tags: git-merge, git-checkout, libgit2, fast-forward

Currently I tried following options:

```
checkout_options.checkout_strategy = GIT_CHECKOUT_SAFE |
GIT_CHECKOUT_ALLOW_CONFLICTS |
GIT_CHECKOUT_CONFLICT_STYLE_MERGE;
checkout_options.checkout_strategy = GIT_CHECKOUT_SAFE |
GIT_CHECKOUT_CONFLICT_STYLE_MERGE;
checkout_options.checkout_strategy = GIT_CHECKOUT_SAFE |
GIT_CHECKOUT_ALLOW_CONFLICTS;
```

The most promising was the first set of flags – perform checkout even when conflicts are expected, and "Write normal merge files for conflicts", as header of `*_STYLE_MERGE` says. I had hoped that this sentence means that in files with conflicts, there gonna be the "<<<<<<<<<<< theirs", etc. preambles wrapping conflicting code blocks. Instead, the file is left untouched. Is there a way to have the preambles, etc. written to files?

Comment: You mean conflicts between edited files in the workdir and files that are different between your current `HEAD` and the tree you're checking out?  That is to say:  are you trying to emulate `git checkout -m`?

Comment: @EdwardThomson: Yes, checkout -m, just tested it. I'm implementing fast forward – after fetch, I checkout the fetched tip and modify heads/<branch> to point to it.